# *ngFor - error no value accessor for form control with name

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I use formGroup in my angular 8 app. Username value I can get, but with *ngFor I get error 
`Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'userRoleMappings'`

`userRoleMappings` need to have an array of roles.

What i doing wrong? Thank you

Here are my HTML and component. And also, here is a video to show you what I need

https://ttprivatenew.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/bozzodj/attachments/11603436/TinyTake02-10-2019-10-14-18.mp4

```js
this.addNewUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: "",
      userRoleMappings: []   //here I need to add array with selected roles
    });
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="addNewUserForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <div class="modal-boy">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h6>Available roles</h6>
                <div class="items1 dragAndDropList" [sortablejs]="userRole" [sortablejsOptions]="options">
                  <div *ngFor="let role of userRole">
                    {{ role }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h6>Selected roles</h6>
                <div class="items2 dragAndDropList" [sortablejs]="selectedRole" [sortablejsOptions]="options">
                  <div *ngFor="let selectedRole of selectedRole" formControlName="userRoleMappings">{{ selectedRole }}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!addNewUserForm.valid">
      Submit Form
     </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: "userRoleMappings need to have an array of roles"  - then you should make `userRoleMappings` a `FormArray`: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: You need remove "formControlName" from the div *ngFor="let selectedRole of ... A formControl (or a formGroup) exist indepently there are a input or not. I supouse you **manually** change the formControl "selectedRoles" when the drag ends using `addNewUserForm.get('userRoleMappings').setValue(selectedRoles)` NOTE: see that you're using the same variable in the *ngFor for individual elements and for the array -I supouse is an error type-

Comment: @mbojko, really it's not necesary using a FormArray, a FormControl can store an array - or even an object- Depending what do you want

Comment: @Eliseo yout answer is correct.